# Possible to joomla model without controller in different files?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am developing small web application(mobile), based on Joomla component. Is it possible to use methods from specific component in custom files? For example now to use core functions such as database i am using something like:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'../');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

require_once(JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php');
require_once(JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php');

$mainframe = &JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$this->db = &JFactory::getDbo();
```

Comment: you want to create standalone app using joomla framework? have a look at [How to create a stand-alone application using the Joomla! Platform](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_stand-alone_application_using_the_Joomla!_Platform)

Comment: @MarkoD not completely. I need to use a few methods from current component in my app, which has nothing to do with joomla...

Comment: you need to include `require_once (JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php');` as well, and to have `configuration.php` file in the root folder. And lose `&`, it will generate notice as of php 5.3+

Comment: Still getting `Notice: Use of undefined constant JPATH_COMPONENT - assumed 'JPATH_COMPONENT'` and as a result in future  a fatal error

Comment: JPATH_COMPONENT is not part of the framework it is par of the CMS so you  want to define that in your application just like the message says. Also it is not necessary to use DS any more since IIS handles slashes fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following.

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php' );

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

Comment: i need to get component's model